# Is there any way track screen for non activity classes in android using firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, controller, firebase-analytics

We are tracking activity screen using firebase

Here is the code.

```
mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);
        mFirebaseAnalytics.setCurrentScreen(this, "HomeActivity", this.getClass().getSimpleName());
```

For some of our screes we are using controller using this library, https://github.com/bluelinelabs/Conductor

How can we track these controllers ?

if we are using this code app is getting crashed

```
mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        mFirebaseAnalytics.setCurrentScreen(getActivity(), "testController", fragment.getClass().getSimpleName());
```

Answer (score 0):

Screen Tracking on Firebase is based on the automatically collected user engagement event by design. The screen view event is triggered when the transition from one screen to another screen occurs.

In absence of screens or activities in background, GA for Firebase won't be able to track the screen event for that activity.